# Appear with sliding effect?

Tags: jquery

I have a div I'm making appear when a form is submitted.

```
document.getElementById('onsubmit').style.display = 'block';
```

I want it to make it appear with a sliding effect. So it moves everything down as it makes size for itself.

I believe it's done with jquery but I have no idea how. Anyone could give me a hand?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the fiddle...

**Demo 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/YRXA4/

**Demo 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/YRXA4/1/

So instead of using the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event, you would use the [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event.

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
$('#onsubmit').slideDown('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```